# Combine tables with one-to-one relations

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I have four tables which store a lot of information about something. This information can be divided into four categories. One category of information is queried always and the other three occasionally.

Since there is a one-to-one relation between all of these tables they could be stored in one table.

My question is: what would be better performance wise?

- One table with queries like `SELECT id, x, y, z FROM all` and `SELECT id, u, v FROM all`
- Multiple tables with queries like `SELECT * FROM xyz` and `SELECT * FROM uv`

(Where `id`, `u`, `v`, `x`, `y` and `z` are columns and `all` is a table with all columns and `xyz` and `uv` are tables with corresponding columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That really depends.

In theory, **relational databases were made to have efficiently relations between tables**. So `SELECT a.x, a.y, a.z FROM a` should be as fast as `SELECT a.x, a.y, b.z from a JOIN b ON a.x = b.x` if a.x and b.x are both the same primary key (eq_ref join).

#### Examples:

- Selecting multiple sequential rows from one big table will be slightly faster than from two small tables thanks to the physical location of the records on the disk.
- Unless the different tables are on different hard-disks, in which case MySQL can fetch them in parallel.
- But this can also be done with one table, using PARTITIONING.
- If certain queries are run more often than others, you might want to optimize for those first. Maybe a covering index solves your problem?
- Using multiple tables also repeats the primary key. But then again, so do indexes on InnoDB.
- With multiple tables, it's harder to maintain integrity. You'll be using FOREIGN KEYS, and transactions for your inserts (or even triggers?)

#### Conclusion:

it really depends on your situation. The best way to find out is to test and benchmark.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll be doing a benchmark soon. Let's say that `x`, `y` and `z` are always queried, but only once in a while these are joined with `u` and `v`. How could I optimize for such a situation?

Comment: It depends on the datatypes of x,y,z, u and v. If they are HUGE variable-length fields, better to seperate them (a table where all columns are fixed length is a lot faster). If they have a fixed length and u & v are not very long, the overhead will be minimal and you might include them. A covering index on x,y,z is possible too, especially if you have a small primary key (like an artificial key, as is best practice).

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon many factors.

Normally one would not do `SELECT * FROM xyz` and `SELECT * FROM uv` when you can just as easily do `SELECT * FROM xyz INNER JOIN uv ON xyz.id = uv.id` when there is a 1-1 relationship.  Even if a relationship is optional, you could use a `LEFT JOIN` just as effectively.

Normally one will not do `SELECT *` and instead only select columns based upon need.